# How to handle mistake, in office

Tags: work-environment, new-job, manager

I recently got job in MNC with reference (manager friend) ,my previous company was small ( friendly relationship in coworkers) . I joined in MNC a week ago, and induction class held on this week, and I was late to the class. My hr , escalated (your candidate did not come on time ,even he got reminder mail) to my manager, his manager... Etc.
My manager called me and asked for reason,I said forgot (actually first day induction class was held 1 hour late, so I thought 2nd day will be same. But unfortunately it started at exact time. I explained this to manager).He asked me what should I reply? I kept quiet. So I became famous in a week. My question is how to handle,When all mistake is my side. One of my friend (who gave reference) in team said manager is very serious on you. And can I survive in this company (because I was escalated in a week) ? To be Frank I was flustered that hr , escalated me for a small reason.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How to handle this type of situation (I made a mistake) how to convince manager. And this type of environment in company is common ? And can I survive in company (I got bad impression in the beginning) ?

Comment: We can't know what the implications at your workplace will be. I would apologize and be very respectful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apologize to everyone who got the email saying you were late - and the instructor.

Do it once, and consider it over.

Be sure in the future to be on time, and ask rather than assuming if you think the time has slipped by an hour.

But forgive yourself - this what an honest mistake.  Don't get flustered - focus on doing a good job.  In a few weeks of diligent work, no one will remember this mistake.  Right now, this is 100% of what your office knows about you - so you're "that guy" but in a few weeks, they will actually know something more about you and hopefully for the better.

If it makes you feel better - in my first month at a new job, I missed the employee/manager brunch, after RSVPing yes, and didn't realize that the big boss had some specifically to meet me.  She inquired politely and I made a lame excuse.

10 years of working with her later - we had a great relationship, she was a great advocate, and I don't think she even remembered that I was the dumb person who stood her up at brunch.  (apparently it stuck with me, though)

Answer (score 1):

There is little you can do. Coming late on a first week appointment communicated in writing is a stupid mistake. Apologize. And mean it.

We do not have a crystal ball concerning your future in this company. Normally, people aren't fired or set back in the long term over a stupid mistake that cost nothing. Chances are good that if you behave properly in the future, nobody will care if you came late last week 6 months from now.

Answer (score 1):

Your first goal is to not get escalated again especially not for a similar reason. So plan to be early for pretty much everything for the next 6 months to a year. They currently think you are unreliable. Show them that you are not and the mistake will be forgotten.

You should also apologize to the trainer in person. Being an hour late for an induction class is a big issue. So far the only thing they know about you is that you are unreliable. That's pretty big. Many people in the HR field have had experience with people who start out being late, then get later and eventually don't run up at all with no notice given. You have made them think of those people. So stop thinking it was a minor mistake. And turn out to be reliable as they get to know you better.

Your next goal is to have the kind of performance that will make them forget about this faster. Being reliable but bad at your job is not good for your future prospects at a company either. Like or not, you messed up and they will be looking at you more closely. Make sure what they see is good. It may not seem fair, but you are going to have to outperform the others who started at the same time to make up for the poor impression.